# React Native - Error : 'currentlyFocusedField' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I'm getting this error `currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput` When the keyboard opens on the `InputText` Did anyone faces the same problem?

The error only appears on iOS devices.

I'm using these dependencies:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
"native-base": "^2.13.14",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
"react-native-screens": "^2.15.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the native base library

I created the PR https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/3305